# These movies are "ONE" of the known movies

Tags: word-usage

I'm writing this article and there is a sentence in it: "These movies are one of the best movies."
I spell-checked it, and the website I used said that *one* should not be used with a plural subject.

Should I omit *one*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two or more things can't be **one** of anything. Only **one** thing can be **one** of the best. When you make **all** these movies the subject of your sentence you have to say something like:

> Each of these movies is one of the best ... *OR*
>   These movies are among the best  ... *OR*
>   These movies are some of the best  ... *OR*
>   These movies are three [or however many of them there are] of the best  ...

Comment: Thanks! Are these examples used only with word "best" or can be used for word "known" , the reason i'm asking this is that it doesn't seem correct to me to say : "These movies are among the known..." is it correct? Thnks!

Comment: @ArdeshirIzadi *Among the known* doesn't work unless it's followed by a noun which *known* modifies: English doesn't much like adjectives and adjectival participles being used as nouns, though there are some circumstances and some adjectives (like *best*) which tolerate it. But *Each of these movies is among the known masterpieces of world cinema* is just fine.

Comment: Or, _These movies are considered to be the best..._

Comment: @StoneyB Why "These movies are among the known masterpieces of world cinema" is not correct?

Comment: @VladimirBezugliy No, that's correct, too. I didn't read your comment closely enough.